# Как "спрятать" сдвиг слайдов при пролистывании с имитацией смены друг друга на месте?

Tags: javascript, css, transform, слайдер, transition

Имеется слайдер на библиотеке `js`. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при пролистывании слайдов не был заметен `transform` сдвиг, а слайды просто плавно сменяли друг друга будучи на одном месте

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // инициализация слайдера
  var slider = new SimpleAdaptiveSlider('.slider', {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 5000,
    swipe: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.slider__item {
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider__item.slider__item_active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #3f51b5;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #607d8b;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #f44336;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #4caf50;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>

**UPD** Хочу добиться примера как [здесь][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это можно отрегулировать в CSS

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const slider = new SimpleAdaptiveSlider('.slider', {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 5000,
    swipe: true,
  });
});
```

```css
.slider__item {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease; 
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute; 
}

.slider__item_active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.5s; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://dmitriy-1986.github.io/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #3f51b5;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #607d8b;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #f44336;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #4caf50;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>

<script src="https://dmitriy-1986.github.io/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: можно, но пролистывание слайдов точно также заметно, как и в моём стартовом примере

Answer (score 1):

В подключенном файле CSS у класса **.slider_items** убираем свойство transition совсем, сама анимация через подключенный JS написана судя по всему. В снипете весь код из подключенного CSS, а искомое свойство закомменчено, так что можете не скачивать его сами, а вот с JS придётся разобраться еще, если Вам это необходимо.

А вообще там где взяли библиотеку должно быть описано как ей собственно пользоваться и какие параметры за что отвечают.

```js
/*var WRAPPER_SELECTOR = ".slider__wrapper",
    ITEMS_SELECTOR = ".slider__items",
    ITEM_SELECTOR = ".slider__item",
    ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE = "slider__item_active",
    CONTROL_SELECTOR = ".slider__control",
    CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW = "slider__control_show",
    INDICATOR_WRAPPER_ELEMENT = "ol",
    INDICATOR_WRAPPER_CLASS = "slider__indicators",
    INDICATOR_ITEM_ELEMENT = "li",
    INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS = "slider__indicator",
    INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE = "slider__indicator_active",
    SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 20,
    TRANSITION_NONE = "transition-none";

function SimpleAdaptiveSlider(t, i) {
    for (var e in this._$root = document.querySelector(t), this._$wrapper = this._$root.querySelector(WRAPPER_SELECTOR), this._$items = this._$root.querySelector(ITEMS_SELECTOR), this._$itemList = this._$root.querySelectorAll(ITEM_SELECTOR), this._currentIndex = 0, this._minOrder = 0, this._maxOrder = 0, this._$itemWithMinOrder = null, this._$itemWithMaxOrder = null, this._minTranslate = 0, this._maxTranslate = 0, this._direction = "next", this._balancingItemsFlag = !1, this._transform = 0, this._hasSwipeState = !1, this._swipeStartPosX = 0, this._intervalId = null, this._config = {
            loop: !0,
            autoplay: !1,
            interval: 5e3,
            swipe: !0
        }, i) this._config.hasOwnProperty(e) && (this._config[e] = i[e]);
    for (var s = 0, n = this._$itemList.length; s < n; s++) this._$itemList[s].dataset.order = s, this._$itemList[s].dataset.index = s, this._$itemList[s].dataset.translate = 0;
    if (this._config.loop) {
        var r = this._$itemList.length - 1,
            a = 100 * -this._$itemList.length;
        this._$itemList[r].dataset.order = -1, this._$itemList[r].dataset.translate = 100 * -this._$itemList.length;
        var o = "translateX(".concat(a, "%)");
        this._$itemList[r].style.transform = o
    }
    this._addIndicators(), this._refreshExtremeValues(), this._setActiveClass(), this._addEventListener(), this._autoplay()
}
SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._setActiveClass = function() {
    var t, i, e, s;
    for (t = 0, i = this._$itemList.length; t < i; t++) e = this._$itemList[t], s = parseInt(e.dataset.index), this._currentIndex === s ? e.classList.add(ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE) : e.classList.remove(ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE);
    var n = this._$root.querySelectorAll("." + INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS);
    if (n.length)
        for (t = 0, i = n.length; t < i; t++) e = n[t], s = parseInt(e.dataset.slideTo), this._currentIndex === s ? e.classList.add(INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE) : e.classList.remove(INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS_ACTIVE);
    var r = this._$root.querySelectorAll(CONTROL_SELECTOR);
    if (r.length)
        if (this._config.loop)
            for (t = 0, i = r.length; t < i; t++) r[t].classList.add(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW);
        else 0 === this._currentIndex ? (r[0].classList.remove(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW), r[1].classList.add(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW)) : this._currentIndex === this._$itemList.length - 1 ? (r[0].classList.add(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW), r[1].classList.remove(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW)) : (r[0].classList.add(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW), r[1].classList.add(CONTROL_CLASS_SHOW))
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._move = function() {
    if ("none" === this._direction) return this._$items.classList.remove(TRANSITION_NONE), void(this._$items.style.transform = "translateX(".concat(this._transform, "%)"));
    if (!this._config.loop) {
        if (this._currentIndex + 1 >= this._$itemList.length && "next" === this._direction) return void this._autoplay("stop");
        if (this._currentIndex <= 0 && "prev" === this._direction) return
    }
    var t = "next" === this._direction ? -100 : 100,
        i = this._transform + t;
    "next" === this._direction ? ++this._currentIndex > this._$itemList.length - 1 && (this._currentIndex -= this._$itemList.length) : --this._currentIndex < 0 && (this._currentIndex += this._$itemList.length), this._transform = i, this._$items.style.transform = "translateX(".concat(i, "%)"), this._setActiveClass()
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._moveTo = function(t) {
    var i = this._currentIndex;
    this._direction = t > i ? "next" : "prev";
    for (var e = 0; e < Math.abs(t - i); e++) this._move()
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._autoplay = function(t) {
    if (this._config.autoplay) return "stop" === t ? (clearInterval(this._intervalId), void(this._intervalId = null)) : void(null === this._intervalId && (this._intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        this._direction = "next", this._move()
    }.bind(this), this._config.interval)))
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._addIndicators = function() {
    if (!this._$root.querySelector("." + INDICATOR_WRAPPER_CLASS)) {
        var t = document.createElement(INDICATOR_WRAPPER_ELEMENT);
        t.className = INDICATOR_WRAPPER_CLASS;
        for (var i = 0, e = this._$itemList.length; i < e; i++) {
            var s = document.createElement(INDICATOR_ITEM_ELEMENT);
            s.className = INDICATOR_ITEM_CLASS, s.dataset.slideTo = i, t.appendChild(s)
        }
        this._$root.appendChild(t)
    }
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._refreshExtremeValues = function() {
    var t = this._$itemList;
    this._minOrder = parseInt(t[0].dataset.order), this._maxOrder = this._minOrder, this._$itemWithMinOrder = t[0], this._$itemWithMaxOrder = this._$itemWithMinOrder, this._minTranslate = parseInt(t[0].dataset.translate), this._maxTranslate = this._minTranslate;
    for (var i = 0, e = t.length; i < e; i++) {
        var s = t[i],
            n = parseInt(s.dataset.order);
        n < this._minOrder ? (this._minOrder = n, this._$itemWithMinOrder = s, this._minTranslate = parseInt(s.dataset.translate)) : n > this._maxOrder && (this._maxOrder = n, this._$itemWithMaxOrder = s, this._minTranslate = parseInt(s.dataset.translate))
    }
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._balancingItems = function() {
    if (this._balancingItemsFlag) {
        var t, i = this._$wrapper.getBoundingClientRect(),
            e = i.width / 2,
            s = this._$itemList.length;
        if ("next" === this._direction) {
            var n = i.left,
                r = this._$itemWithMinOrder;
            t = this._minTranslate, r.getBoundingClientRect().right < n - e && (r.dataset.order = this._minOrder + s, t += 100 * s, r.dataset.translate = t, r.style.transform = "translateX(".concat(t, "%)"), this._refreshExtremeValues())
        } else if ("prev" === this._direction) {
            var a = i.right,
                o = this._$itemWithMaxOrder;
            t = this._maxTranslate, o.getBoundingClientRect().left > a + e && (o.dataset.order = this._maxOrder - s, t -= 100 * s, o.dataset.translate = t, o.style.transform = "translateX(".concat(t, "%)"), this._refreshExtremeValues())
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(this._balancingItems.bind(this))
    }
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype._addEventListener = function() {
    var t = this._$items;

    function i(t) {
        this._autoplay("stop");
        var i = 0 === t.type.search("touch") ? t.touches[0] : t;
        this._swipeStartPosX = i.clientX, this._swipeStartPosY = i.clientY, this._hasSwipeState = !0, this._hasSwiping = !1
    }

    function e(t) {
        if (this._hasSwipeState) {
            var i = 0 === t.type.search("touch") ? t.touches[0] : t,
                e = this._swipeStartPosX - i.clientX,
                s = this._swipeStartPosY - i.clientY;
            if (!this._hasSwiping) {
                if (Math.abs(s) > Math.abs(e)) return void(this._hasSwipeState = !1);
                this._hasSwiping = !0
            }
            t.preventDefault(), this._config.loop || (this._currentIndex + 1 >= this._$itemList.length && e >= 0 && (e /= 4), this._currentIndex <= 0 && e <= 0 && (e /= 4));
            var n = e / this._$wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width * 100,
                r = this._transform - n;
            this._$items.classList.add(TRANSITION_NONE), this._$items.style.transform = "translateX(".concat(r, "%)")
        }
    }

    function s(t) {
        if (this._hasSwipeState) {
            var i = 0 === t.type.search("touch") ? t.changedTouches[0] : t,
                e = this._swipeStartPosX - i.clientX;
            this._config.loop || (this._currentIndex + 1 >= this._$itemList.length && e >= 0 && (e /= 4), this._currentIndex <= 0 && e <= 0 && (e /= 4));
            var s = e / this._$wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().width * 100;
            this._$items.classList.remove(TRANSITION_NONE), s > SWIPE_THRESHOLD ? (this._direction = "next", this._move()) : s < -SWIPE_THRESHOLD ? (this._direction = "prev", this._move()) : (this._direction = "none", this._move()), this._hasSwipeState = !1, this._config.loop && this._autoplay()
        }
    }
    if (this._$root.addEventListener("click", function(t) {
            var i = t.target;
            if (this._autoplay("stop"), i.classList.contains("slider__control")) t.preventDefault(), this._direction = i.dataset.slide, this._move();
            else if (i.dataset.slideTo) {
                t.preventDefault();
                var e = parseInt(i.dataset.slideTo);
                this._moveTo(e)
            }
            this._config.loop && this._autoplay()
        }.bind(this)), this._config.loop && (t.addEventListener("transitionstart", function() {
            this._balancingItemsFlag = !0, window.requestAnimationFrame(this._balancingItems.bind(this))
        }.bind(this)), t.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
            this._balancingItemsFlag = !1
        }.bind(this))), this._config.autoplay && (this._$root.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
            this._autoplay("stop")
        }.bind(this)), this._$root.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
            this._config.loop && this._autoplay()
        }.bind(this))), this._config.swipe) {
        var n = !1;
        try {
            var r = Object.defineProperty({}, "passive", {
                get: function() {
                    n = !0
                }
            });
            window.addEventListener("testPassiveListener", null, r)
        } catch (t) {}
        this._$root.addEventListener("touchstart", i.bind(this), !!n && {
            passive: !1
        }), this._$root.addEventListener("touchmove", e.bind(this), !!n && {
            passive: !1
        }), this._$root.addEventListener("mousedown", i.bind(this)), this._$root.addEventListener("mousemove", e.bind(this)), document.addEventListener("touchend", s.bind(this)), document.addEventListener("mouseup", s.bind(this))
    }
    this._$root.addEventListener("dragstart", function(t) {
        t.preventDefault()
    }.bind(this)), document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        "hidden" === document.visibilityState ? this._autoplay("stop") : "visible" === document.visibilityState && this._config.loop && this._autoplay()
    }.bind(this))
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype.next = function() {
    this._direction = "next", this._move()
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype.prev = function() {
    this._direction = "prev", this._move()
}, SimpleAdaptiveSlider.prototype.autoplay = function(t) {
    this._autoplay("stop")
};*/

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // инициализация слайдера
  var slider = new SimpleAdaptiveSlider('.slider', {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 5000,
    swipe: true,
  });
});
```

```css
/* ВАШA CSS */

.slider__item {
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider__item.slider__item_active {
  opacity: 1;
}

                                              /* ПОДКЛЮЧЕННАЯ CSS */

.slider{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}

.slider__wrapper{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#eee
}

.slider__items{
    display:flex;
/*  transition:transform .5s ease */
}

.transition-none{
    transition:none
}

.slider__item{
    flex:0 0 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    position:relative
}

.slider__control{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:40px;height:50px;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    display:none;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    color:#fff;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    opacity:.5;user-select:none
}

.slider__control_show{
    display:flex
}

.slider__control:focus,
.slider__control:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:.7
}

.slider__control_prev{
    left:0
}

.slider__control_next{
    right:0
}

.slider__control::before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;height:20px;
    background:transparent no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% 100%
}

.slider__control_prev::before{
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}

.slider__control_next::before{
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}

.slider__indicators{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    bottom:10px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    padding-left:0;
    margin:0 15%;
    list-style:none;
    user-select:none
}

.slider__indicator{
    flex:0 1 auto;
    width:30px;height:4px;
    margin-right:3px;
    margin-left:3px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    background-clip:padding-box;
    border-top:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
    cursor:pointer
}

.slider__indicator_active{
    background-color:#fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.js"></script>

<!-- ОТКЛЮЧАЕМ CSS НА ВСЯКИЙ СЛУЧАЙ 
<link href="https://itchief.ru/examples/libs/simple-adaptive-slider/simple-adaptive-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  -->
 
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
    <div class="slider__items">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #3f51b5;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #607d8b;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #f44336;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: #4caf50;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a class="slider__control slider__control_next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Если нужен JS в более менее нормальном виде насколько я смог его вытащить, то тоже могу добавить.

Comment: хотелось бы, чтобы слайды плавно сменяли друг драга без пропадания
`должно быть описано как ей собственно пользоваться и какие параметры за что отвечают`
нет, там это не описано и нет подобных примеров - везде слайды пролистываются

Comment: @Вася в ответ добавил код скрипта и закомментил его, но увы самому разобраться с ним пока не понимаю как в силу неопытности.